# Laravel Blade templates are rendered 2 times

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Take this (non) blade script `list.blade.php` :

```
<?php
error_log( print_r( "START" , true ) );

global $i;

for ( $a = 0 ; $a < 3 ; $a++ ) {
    $j = @(int)$i;

    error_log( print_r( $j , true ) );
    echo $j;

    $i = $j + 1 ;
}

error_log( print_r( "STOP" , true ) );
```

The expected result should be `012` but the output is `345` !

If you check your server error logs, you can see this :

```
START
0
1
2
STOP
START
3
4
5
STOP
```

Therefore the template is ran a first time without outputting anything and it is ran a second time and the output is then sent.

I use an updated Laravel 4.2 version. It is not really a problem but when each parsed row is requesting heavy computing task, the load time is just X2.

Do you think it is a bug or is it a normal behaviour ?

Is there a way to avoid some executions in the template on the first launch (dry run) ?

Comment: where are you including this template? And the usage of global just freaks me out. Use decorators if you want to passin extra data

Comment: This template is just a PoC. Global is just used to keep the state between several loads to show you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem found, but not the solution! I use my Laravel boilerplate but it is the culprit. I use a global after filter to minify HTML code on the fly (added error logs for this question):

```
App::after(function ($request, $response) {

    // Minify only texts
    if ( strpos( $response->headers->get('content-type') , 'text/' ) !== false ) {
        if ($response instanceof Illuminate\Http\Response) {

error_log( print_r( 'coucou1' , true ) );
            $output = $response->getOriginalContent();
error_log( print_r( 'coucou2' , true ) );

            $re = '%# Collapse whitespace everywhere but in blacklisted elements.
            (?>             # Match all whitespans other than single space.
            [^\S ]\s*     # Either one [\t\r\n\f\v] and zero or more ws,
            | \s{2,}        # or two or more consecutive-any-whitespace.
            ) # Note: The remaining regex consumes no text at all...
            (?=             # Ensure we are not in a blacklist tag.
            [^<]*+        # Either zero or more non-"<" {normal*}
            (?:           # Begin {(special normal*)*} construct
            <           # or a < starting a non-blacklist tag.
            (?!/?(?:textarea|pre|script)\b)
            [^<]*+      # more non-"<" {normal*}
            )*+           # Finish "unrolling-the-loop"
            (?:           # Begin alternation group.
            <           # Either a blacklist start tag.
            (?>textarea|pre|script)\b
            | \z          # or end of file.
            )             # End alternation group.
            )  # If we made it here, we are not in a blacklist tag.
            %Six';

error_log( print_r( 'coucou3' , true ) );

            $output = preg_replace( $re , " " , $output );

error_log( print_r( 'coucou4' , true ) );
            if ($output !== null) {
                $response->setContent($output);
            }
error_log( print_r( 'coucou5' , true ) );
        }
    }

});
```

and the error log result is really surprising :

```
START
0
1
2
STOP
coucou1
coucou2
coucou3
START
3
4
5
STOP
coucou4
coucou5
```

The blade template is evaluated the second time on the following line :

```
$output = preg_replace( $re , " " , $output );
```

Which is not possible in PHP... I think I miss a Laravel architecture design... If someone understand anything...

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer. I just tested with your code and got the result `012`. I tested it with version 4.2.6. I have no idea how you got it.

Here's the code I used.

app/route.php

```
Route::get("test",function(){
    return View::make("aaa");
});
```

app/views/aaa.blade.php

```
<?php
error_log( print_r( "START" , true ) );

global $i;

for ( $a = 0 ; $a < 3 ; $a++ ) {
    $j = @(int)$i;

    error_log( print_r( $j , true ) );
    echo $j;

    $i = $j + 1 ;
}

error_log( print_r( "STOP" , true ) );
```

Comment: You are right! I use my Laravel boilerplate but it is the culprit. I use an after filter to minify HTML code on the fly. I will answer to my question.